# Standard UIButton blink animation not working on IOS 8 only if title is only set programatically

Tags: ios, animation, ios8, uibutton

I have a UIButton of type:System and title:Plain added to my view with IB.

The title of the UIButton is blank in IB.

The title is set programmatically with `[.button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"title", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

On IOS 9 the button has the standard blink animation when tapped.

On IOS 8 the button doesn't have the standard blink animation when tapped.

If I set a title for the button's default state in IB then the standard blink animation starts working on IOS 8.

The trouble is I have a lot of buttons like this and adding garbage titles for all of them in IB will be confusing for translators.

Is there another way to fix this for IOS 8?

Comment: It's working very well on all cases, I tested it. Can you share any sample code with this problem, I'll fix it? Via dropbox maybe.

Comment: @Shamsiddin Thank you for your help. I have trying to reproduce this in a simple test app. I will upload it when I can reproduce it.